# Why can't g++ (and clang++) avoid string construction here?

Tags: c++, g++, compiler-optimization, clang++, copy-elision

If we write:

```
std::string foo(const bool b) {
    if (b) {
        return "Hello";
    }
    else {
        return "World";
    }
}
```

g++ and clang++  will not call a string constructor, but rather manipulate the return string in-place. On the other hand, if we use this style:

```
std::string bar(const bool b) {
    std::string ret;
    if (b) {
        ret = "Hello";
    }
    else {
        ret = "World";
    }
    return ret;
}
```

the string class constructor is called, even when compiling with maximum optimization (`-O3`), and this being a "simple" function. where the next C++ instruction after the assignment is an unconditional return.

(See both examples on [<kbd>GodBolt</kbd>](https://godbolt.org/z/TTWdq8))

Is this just a missed optimization opportunity in clang++ and g++, or is something compelling them to call the constructor?

<sub>This question was inspired by [this C++ Weekly episode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9mWWNYRHAIQ).</sub>

Comment: NRVO is optional.  Most compilers only do the easiest examples, ie: `int foo() { int bar = 10; return bar; }`

Comment: @NathanOliver: But, I said the magic words... `-O3` :-(

Comment: I don't think there's any reason why a compiler *wouldn't* be able to do NRVO here. (apart from implementation difficulties of course).

Comment: The compiler must also prove that using a default constructor followed by an overloaded assignment operator can be optimized to using a different constructor without any observable effects of this optimization.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: Isn't it enough to prove that both of these don't have an observable effect other than what's in the resulting string?

Comment: Hm, isn't that exactly what I wrote?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: I should have said "observable effect outside the scope of the function".

Comment: Perhaps, but how is that any different from what I wrote? The point is that it's pretty easy for you, a carbon-based life form, to simply look at the code and know that. But a compiler is a beast of logic, and must examine what `std::string`'s constructor does, step by step. Then do the same with the overloaded assignment operator also does, step by step, and then figure out that optimizing it away in this manner does not result in any observable change.